# How to retrieve Avatar images of users in Quickblox

Tags: blob, quickblox, avatar

I am using Quickblox API and successfully uploading, fetching and retrieving the Avatar image of the user.But in my app i want to show the list of users when a user logs in. How to get the users avatars.

I am getting the list of users (QBUsers) but in that BlobId is Null for everyone, though Avatar images are existing for the users.

Please help me for fetching avatars of the users.

Answer (score 1):

```
 func downloadTeamMemberAvatar(avatarFileId:String,completion:      (UIImage?)->Void){

    let id = UInt(avatarFileId)

    if let _ = id{

        QBRequest.downloadFileWithID(id!, successBlock: { (_, imageData) in

            let image = UIImage(data:imageData)

            completion(image)

            }, statusBlock: { (_, _) in

            }, errorBlock: { (_) in

                completion(nil)
        })

    }else{completion(nil)}

}
```

Comment: Please, look at this [question's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043763/how-to-upload-the-users-profile-pic-and-how-to-fetch-that-profile-pic-from-anoth/37048260#37048260)