# How to upload the Users profile pic and how to fetch that profile pic from another users device?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, blob, quickblox

I have a requirement,Lets say there are 3-Users for my app. I want to add an image(Profile pic purpose) to each user so that this image can be visible to other two users who are using the same app. Just like whatsapp profile pics. So for this purpose I did the following things.

Step 1 : **Logged in as User1** 
then I added this code to upload image file. After I logged in with User1 credentials and I made Public property as YES while uploading file.

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]);

[QBRequest TUploadFile:imageData fileName:@"arrow.png" contentType:@"image/png" isPublic:YES successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBCBlob *blob) {

} statusBlock:^(QBRequest *request, QBRequestStatus *status) {
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
}];
```

Step 2 : **Logged in as User2**

Then I did like this I'm fetching all the users belongs to my app. using

```
QBGeneralResponsePage *responsePage = [QBGeneralResponsePage responsePageWithCurrentPage:currentPage perPage:perPage];

[QBRequest usersForPage:responsePage successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBGeneralResponsePage *page, NSArray *users) {

    weakSelf.allUsers = [users mutablecopy]
    [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];

} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

}];
```

Step 3 : 
Now I have all the users so I'm doing iteration to find the users blob id .

```
    QBUUser *user = (QBUUser *)self.allUsers[indexPath.row];


if (user.blobID != 0) {

    [QBRequest downloadFileWithID:user.blobID successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSData *fileData) {

        UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:fileData];
        [cell.imageView setImage:img];

    } statusBlock:^(QBRequest *request, QBRequestStatus *status) {

    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

    }];
}
```

But the problem is here I'm not getting any blobID with the User1 means **blobID of user1 as 0**(all users blobID as 0), But while uploading it was success and I got blobID after uploading the file using User1 as logged in.

But when **I logged in as user2 or User3** it is not showing any blobID associated with user1. And I made Public as Yes while uploading.
Is this correct way of doing or any mistake I'm doing please let me know ?

Comment: please check your server side, may be some problem in your API , URl, and  may possible your uploading is successful but not stored in DB.

Comment: There is no issue. It is storing in admin.quickblox.com

Comment: There is no problem with the response. I'm getting QBBlob once Upload is success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update user's blobID using request with QBUpdateUserParameters after blob's uploading:

```
      [QBRequest TUploadFile:imageData fileName:@"arrow.png" contentType:@"image/png" isPublic:YES successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBCBlob *blob) {

            QBUpdateUserParameters *userParams = [QBUpdateUserParameters new];
            userParams.blobID = blob.ID;

            [QBRequest updateCurrentUser:userParams successBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull __unused response, QBUUser * _Nullable user) {
            } errorBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response) {

            }];

        } statusBlock:^(QBRequest *request, QBRequestStatus *status) {

        } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
        }];
```

Comment: Yeah its working sir, Thank you so much. And I have two doubts in this. 1. Weather we should keep IsPublic  as YES or NO. When we should use YES and NO.

Comment: 2. In response blob. I saw one property called expires. It is like this : expires:2016-05-05T08:54:01Z. What this property will do. Weather this is telling about the expiry time of the uploaded file ?

Comment: You are really awesome sir. I'm worked on this for whole day but I didn't got the solution. I did as it is told in the document. But it didn't work. With your solution its working fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Wills-In [Info](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-content-ios#Public.2FPrivate_urls) about isPublic property

Comment: sir can i be in contact with you through mails. I am really interested to know about quick blox its really good.Here is my mail id : myiosgallery@gmail.com please drop me a mail so that we can be in contact I won't disturb you much but if i got any doubt i will mail you sir also i will post the same question in stack overflow also So that other can also find solutions for their queries

Comment: @Wills-In you can create separate issue for your question on our [github repo](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk). Fell free to ask

Comment: @Wills-In  as  to "expires" field  - it's an old and unimportant field , which is not used for now.

Comment: Ok thank you. Sir, I got one more doubt I posted it as new one please check this.( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066109/how-to-give-photo-to-dialog-from-users-blob-id ) Doubt is how to add this profile pic of other user to the private dialogue that we are creating.

Comment: Hi Sir, There is one guy responded to my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066109/how-to-give-photo-to-dialog-from-users-blob-id) And he is telling that he has handled the core data himself cause he didn't users QMServices so How to do that in my project using QMServices and is there any alternate or better way than what he has suggested for me for my Question 1 & 2.

Comment: V.Guru quickblox , I'm waiting for your valuable answer